# Transposing CLI code to CloudFormation JSON format

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a requirement to create a JSON Template for CloudFormation, from some AWS CLI code. The code includes creating a VPC, gateways, subnets, route tables and so forth

I need to convert these in a way accepted by CloudFormation and not sure the most efficient way to do that. Surely, there must be a way to automate this?

I also need to create variables that can be referenced through the template, and I don't remember the last time I did that with JSON. Is there a tutorial or reference for these stuff?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for checking up. The resources were not deployed already, so former2 wouldn't work. My current ask is to help integrate Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines with AWS CloudFormation. The requirement is to have the stuff pulled from Azure DevOps to CloudFormation where the IaC is then deployed. Part of this involves transforming some CLI code to CloudFormation as mentioned above but now I'm stuck on integrating Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines with Cloudformation - can't even find much info about this setup online.

Comment: There is no such tool. You need fully custom solution for that.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Surely, there must be a way to automate this?

No there is not automated conversion from CLI to cloudformation. However, if the resources have been already deployed, you can use [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) to generate the templates automatically.